# How can I convert an array of objects to a basic object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I would like to convert

```
const conditions = [
    {products: [] },
    {hairday: []},
    {drying: []},
    {rating: []}
];
```

to

```
const conditions = {
  products: [],
  hairday: [],
  drying: [],
  rating: []
};
```

What is the best way to acheive this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Note that the keys must be unique in order for it to work.

Comment: You use something like: `Object.assign({}, ...conditions);`

Comment: OMG @NickParsons that's amazing. Thank you so much